# APEX test script to web server with a static time stamp doget cakk and HttpGet

Tags: unit-test, datetime, post, restresource

New to writing test scripts. Looking for help in error in Unexpected token 'Lead' for my test code. I have a static field that pulls off time stamp to only pull data after a certain time. I am currently at 70% code coverage however the test class is erroring on "Class.NewLeads.doGet: line 8, column 1
Class.NewLeadTest.testMethod1: line 12, column 1"

```
@isTest
private class NewLeadTest
{
  static testMethod void testMethod1()
    {

       RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
       RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

       req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/NewLeads?time_stamp=07/10/2019+12:36+PM';
       req.httpMethod = 'GET';

       RestContext.request = req;
       RestContext.response = res;

       List returnList = NewLeads.doGet() ;

}
@isTest
      static void NewLeadPost()
      {
```

```
   RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
   RestResponse res = new RestResponse();    
   req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/NewLeads?time_stamp=07/10/2019+12:36+PM';
   req.httpMethod = 'POST';     
   RestContext.request = req;
   RestContext.response = res;

   List<Lead> lds = new List<Lead>(); 
   Lead leadToCreate = new Lead();
   leadtoCreate.FirstName = 'Ray';
   leadToCreate.LastName = 'Lewis';
   leadToCreate.Middlename = 'Andy';
   leadtoCreate.Phone = '678-782-1111';
   leadtoCreate.Street = '234 State Route Clarkston';
   leadtoCreate.City = 'Dawson';
   leadtoCreate.StateCode = 'GA';
   leadtoCreate.PostalCode = '30034';
   leadtoCreate.Email = 'Ray.lewis@ymail.com';
   lds.add(leadToCreate);

   NewLeads.doPost(lds);
```

}
}

@RestResource (urlMapping='/NewLeads')
global with sharing class NewLeads 
{
    @HttpGet
    global static Lead[] doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String time_stamp = req.params.get('time_stamp');
        Datetime dt = DateTime.parse(time_stamp);
        Lead[] Leads = [Select
                            Firstname,
                            Lastname,
                            Middlename,
                            Suffix,
                            Phone,
                            Secondary_phone__c,
                            Street,
                            City,
                            Statecode,
                            Postalcode,
                            Country,
                            Region__c,
                            Date_of_birth__c,
                            Age__c,
                            Email

from Lead 
                        WHERE CreatedDate > :dt
                   ];
    return Leads;
}


@HttpPost 
global static String doPost(Lead[] Leads) { 
    upsert leads; 
    return Leads[0].LastName; }
}

Comment: P.S. Your doPost method could be written as: `@HttpPost
global static String doPost(Lead[] Leads) { upsert leads; return Leads[0].LastName; }` This would help increase code coverage with less complexity.

Comment: P.P.S. Consider using a ISO 8601-formatted time stamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) in GMT, and use DateTime.valueOfGmt. This avoids time zone errors and locale settings that you may get using DateTime.parse.

Comment: Thank you I was able to update the HttpPost Code.

Comment: Hi I am almost at code coverage for this class. Is there anything else you see that can help me clear the code? I have update the code with my latest changes.

Comment: Your code is kind of screwed up (copy-paste error?). If you called the two methods, you should get 100% coverage.

Comment: Yep user error i didn't paste the whole code updated now. I called both methods but still only 70% The HttpPost I get full coverage the doGet I am not.

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma between the last field in the SELECT clause and the FROM clause

```
ce,

      from Lead
```